# How do I create chart from this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I am very new to javascript and am trying to create a chart from this JSON:

```
{
  "sid":10381,
  "dataunit":"kW",
  "data":[
    {
      "time":"00:00",
      "no":"0",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    {
      "time":"00:20",
      "no":"2",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    {
      "time":"00:40",
      "no":"4",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

Now I would like to plot "time" as my x and "value" as my y. ("value" is different than zero later in JSON). I tried following this tutorial:

https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/javascript-charts-from-json-data-api-and-ajax/

..but I had no luck getting it to work, I am confused with the part after $.getJSON .

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Hi interesting, not sure if this is of interest https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-line-chart/

Comment: My main problem is getting datapoints from json into js.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to get data point :

```
var sample_json = {
  "sid":10381,
  "dataunit":"kW",
  "data":[
    {
      "time":"00:00",
      "no":"0",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    {
      "time":"00:20",
      "no":"2",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    {
      "time":"00:40",
      "no":"4",
      "value":"0.00"
    },
    // ...
  ]
};
var data = sample_json['data'];
var i;
var data_point = [];
var point = [];
for(i =0;i< data.length; i++){
  point = [];
  point.push(data[i]['time']);
  point.push(data[i]['value']);
  data_point.push(point);

  console.log(data_point);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use JSON for a chart, i use this code:

```
let dataRequest = new Request("./datas/my_jsonf_file.json");

    await fetch(dataRequest)
        .then(function(resp) {
            return resp.json();
        })
        .then(
            async function(data) {
                this.dadosJSON = await Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
                    return [key, data[key]];
                });
            });

    let data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.dadosJSON);
```

to catch this JSON:

```
{
    "Month": "Value",
    "Out": 50,
    "Nov": 23,
    "Dez": 45
}
```

Key in my javascript code catch the mounth and data[key] the value.